# Non-counital coalgebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, monoidal-categories, coalgebras

For any unital algebra $A$, we have an associated dual coalgebra $A^{\circ}$. (Recall that it is defined to be the largest subalgebra of the $\mathbf{C}$-linear dual of $A$ such that the coproduct $\Delta(f)(a,b) = f(ab)$ is well-defined.) What is the corresponding construction for a non-unital algebra. The coproduct part still works, but we have no counit, since this should arise as the dual of the unit. So are non-counital coalgebras studied in the literature? If so what are some references?

Comment: Non-counital coalgebras are used in [Aguiar's *Infinitesimal Hopf algebras*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~maguiar/cor.pdf) (they form part of the structure of the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite dual of a non-unital algebra has been introduced in [Semiperfect and coreflexive coalgebras, S. Dăscălescu, M. C. Iovanov, Forum Math. 27 (2015), No. 5, 2587--2608](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/form/27/5/form.27.issue-5.xml). See also: [arXiv:1512.09344 [math.RT]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.09344).

For the (more general) notion of noncounital corings (and some relevant examples) you can also see ch.4, sect. 26 of [Corings and comodules, T. Brzezinski, R. Wisbauer](https://www.cambridge.org/gr/academic/subjects/mathematics/algebra/corings-and-comodules?format=PB&isbn=9780521539319)